# ZAP Daemon listening at localhost

Tags: docker, localhost, daemon, zap

i'm running ZAP daemon, listening to localhost and running some test. The problem is, i don't get any result back, it just keep listening to localhost. 
Does anyone knows how can i fix that? Is there some more specific documentation about the Daemon?

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computing)

Comment: I guess was too superficial with the question. I'm actually doing something more complex. I'm trying to integrate ZAP in my E2E tests with Cypress. (Here there's a example under "Using ZAP with End to End Tests" link). I'm running ZAP Docker image, and on the other side my E2E in another Docker container, and i bridged them together. But unfortunately, as i said, i'm not able to see the results from ZAP.

Answer (score 0):

ZAP exposes a powerful API that allows you to do nearly everything that the desktop UI can do: https://www.zaproxy.org/docs/api/

Comment: Sorry Simon, i guess i resumed my question a bit too much. I'm actually doing something  more complex. I'm trying to integrate ZAP in my E2E tests with Cypress. (Here there's a example under "Using ZAP with End to End Tests" [link](https://www.nearform.com/blog/zed-attack-proxy-in-a-ci-pipeline/)). I'm running ZAP Docker image, and on the other side my E2E in another Docker container, and i bridged them together. But unfortunately, as i said, i'm not able to see the results from ZAP.

Comment: I'm forwarding the traffic from Cypress to the ZAP container using this env variable: `PROXY_HTTPS=http://zapcontaineraddress:8080 npx cypress run `